# Prove or Disprove: Given an infinite collection of disjoint subsets $(X_n)_{n \in \Bbb N},$ of $\Bbb R,$ the union has to be all of $\Bbb R.$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

I currently believe this to be false, because $n$ must be a natural number thus $n$ can never be a fraction. So taking the union of a set of natural numbers would not result in the complete set of $\Bbb R.$

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Is the index set meant to be the natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Your argument is completely wrong.  The index, n, has nothing to do with the *elements* inside $X_n $.  Example if $X_n $ is the interval $[n+6,2+7) $ the union *is* R, and $n \not \in X_n $.  But in general the statement is obviously and trivially false.  Just let $X_n=\{n\} $ and the union is only N.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: what if I take $X_n = \{n\}$?

**Addendum**: Note that $n$ is just a *dummy variable* used to index the sequence of sets $(X_n)_n$. Your original reasoning is flawed, because one could take $X_1=\mathbb{R}$ and $X_2=X_3=\cdots=\emptyset$, thereby obtaining $\cup_n X_n = X_1 = \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I see so n represents the amount of sets. So it would be logical to say the collection of sets is equal to **R** correct?

Comment: The collection could be *any* collection of sets. Why would that be all of R? They could all be sets of irrational numbers. Or sets of tationals. Or each set could be an interval from k+1/2 to k+3/4 for different integer for each set. an infinite collection of sets can be all R or not so the statement is very false., but the indexing has nothing to do with the content of the sets.